# How to display Renew date automatically based on plan selection (Monthly, Yearly) in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple subscription plans like (1 Month, 3 Months, 6 Months, 1 Year). If the user selects a particular plan, I have to display the renewal date on the below Input box automatically.

Here is My code:

```js
const plandata = [
  {name: "1 Month", value: '1 Month'},
  {name: "3 Month", value: '3 Months'},
  {name: "6 Month", value: '6 Months'},
  {name: "1 Year", value: '1 Year'}
];

...

<Form.Group as={Row}>
  <Form.Label className='add_sub_form_group' column xl={3} >
    <span>*</span>Choose Your Plan
  </Form.Label>
  <Col xl={8} >
    <ButtonGroup className= 'add_sub_btn_group' toggle>
      {
        plandata.map((d,idx)=>(
          <ToggleButton variant="outline-success"
            className='add_sub_plan_btn'
            type='radio'
            name='plan'
            required
            value={d.value}
            checked={subscriber.plan === d.value}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
              {d.name}
          </ToggleButton>
        ))
      }
    </ButtonGroup>
  </Col>
</Form.Group>
<Form.Group as={Row}>
  <Form.Label className='add_sub_form_group' column xl={3} >
    <span>*</span>Renew Date
  </Form.Label>
  <Col xl={8}>
    <Form.Control
      className='input_text'
      required placeholder="31 april 2021"
      disabled
      value={subscriber.renew}
      name='renew'
      onChange={handleChange} />
  </Col>
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a library to handle dates like `date-fns` and simply add the value selected to today. For example, if you add a month:

```js
var result = add(new Date(), {
  months: 1,
})
```

Here are the docs: https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/add

Let me know if this helps or if you need more clarification.

Cheers!

Comment: need small help how to change date format. I mean i need only DD/MM/YYYY but i am getting this format ***Sat Feb 06 2021 14:58:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: Code: *************** const selPlan = subscriber.plan
        
        if(selPlan==="1"){
            return add (new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0],{
                months:1
            })
           
        } *****************

Comment: you can do it with the same library as before. Here are the docs for formatting: https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format
But apply the format to the result of the `add` operation, not before.